# error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, file

hello I want to spawn gams from java I have installed gams and here is the code
gams is an application for modelling I want to call it from java and I am sure the path is exact what should i do to correct it? it gives me exception
EXCEPTIONS:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
            at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:441)
            at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
            at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:466)
            at gams.RunGAMS.main(RunGAMS.java:27)

Java Result: 1
```

here is the code which I changed from [this link](http://interfaces.gams-software.com/doku.php?id=env%3aspawning_gams_from_java)

```
package gams;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class RunGAMS {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
              System.out.println("Start");
              String[] cmdArray = new String[5];
              cmdArray[0] ="C:"+File.separator+"Program Files"+File.separator+"GAMS23.7" + File.separator +"gams.exe";
              cmdArray[1] ="C:"+File.separator+"Documents and Settings"+File.separator+"Parsa"+File.separator+"My Documents"+File.separator+"gamsdir"+File.separator+"projdir" + File.separator +"trnsport.gms";
              cmdArray[2] ="C:"+File.separator+"Documents and Settings"+File.separator+"Parsa"+File.separator+".nbi"+ File.separator+"tmp";
              cmdArray[3] ="LO=3";

              try {
                     Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray);
                     BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                     String s = null;
                     while((s=stdInput.readLine()) !=null){
                        System.out.println(s);
                     }
                     p.waitFor();

              }
              catch (java.io.IOException e )
              {
                     System.err.println(">>>>" + e.getMessage() );
                     e.printStackTrace();
              }
              catch (InterruptedException e )

              {
                     System.err.println(">>>>" + e.getMessage() );
                     e.printStackTrace();
              }
              System.out.println("Done");
      }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
String[] cmdArray = new String[5];
cmdArray[0] = ...;
cmdArray[1] = ...;
cmdArray[2] = ...;
cmdArray[3] = ...;
```

You're creating an array of *five* elements but only populating *four* of them.

Try changing the array size to 4, if you only want four arguments.

Answer (score 2):

A way to avoid creating array which is the wrong sized is to use a one liner.

```
String sep = File.separator;
String[] cmdArray = {
          "C:"+sep+"Program Files"+sep+"GAMS23.7" + sep +"gams.exe",
          "C:"+sep+"Documents and Settings"+sep+"Parsa"+sep+"My Documents"+sep+"gamsdir"+sep+"projdir" + sep +"trnsport.gms",
          "C:"+sep+"Documents and Settings"+sep+"Parsa"+sep+".nbi"+ sep+"tmp",
          "LO=3"};
```

or to make it shorter.

```
String[] cmdArray = "C:/Program Files/GAMS23.7/gams.exe,C:/Documents and Settings/Parsa/My Documents/gamsdir/projdir/trnsport.gms,C:/Documents and Settings/Parsa/.nbi/tmp,LO=3".replaceAll("/", File.separator).split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a space in your path , just look at following lines,

```
cmdArray[0] ="C:"+File.separator+"Program Files"+File.separator+"GAMS23.7" + File.separator +"gams.exe";
```

Here in this line you have defined "Program Files" which contans a space, so basically your variable cmdArray[0] is storing only holding value like = C:\Program , it is terminating after the space. Same way it is happening with other array elements , so it is giving a Nul Pointer Exception.